# Synchronization by this doesn't prevent concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

I'm very novice in multithreading in java, so would be very appreciate if someone give me brief explanation of the following:

here is my code:

```
public class Lesson6 {
    private static volatile Long value = 0L;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread inc = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) {
                    synchronized (this){
                        ++value;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        inc.start();

        Thread dec = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) {
                    synchronized (this){
                        --value;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        dec.start();

        inc.join();
        dec.join();

        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

It seems for me, that the output should be zero, but it's never zero. Debugger shows that THIS is always different from time to time as run() methods go. Why does this happen?

Thanx.

Comment: ‘this’ is incorrect. This is twi different objects, so different sync monitors. Do use same object, e.g. ‘final Object lock= new Object();’

Comment: You have to lock on the same object. `this` is different for each object.

Comment: Most likely you want to make `value` a primitive `long` not a reference to  a `Long`

Comment: Do use  ‘Lesson6.class’ instead of ‘this’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Debugger shows that THIS is always different from time to time as run() methods go

Each `new Runnable` is a different object so `this` is different in each case.

If you use a common object, the program should work.

BTW I suggest using a primitive `long` for the value instead of a reference to a `Long`

```
public class Lesson6 {
    private static volatile long value = 0L;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Object locked = new Object();
        Thread inc = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) {
                    synchronized (locked){
                        ++value;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        inc.start();

        Thread dec = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) {
                    synchronized (locked){
                        --value;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        dec.start();

        inc.join();
        dec.join();

        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

prints

```
0
```

Comment: So simple...Thanks a lot!